# Get rid of space between divs - CSS

Tags: css, html, whitespace

I have the following HTML code where the `subnav` div is a collection of `div` tags that will act as tabs across the `featuredexhibit` div.  Problem is that there is a white space adding between the top of the `featureexhibit` div and bottom of the `subnav` tab.

HTML:

```
<div id="subnav">
    <div id="subnavtab"><a href="">Plan Your Visit</a></div>
    <div id="subnavtab"><a href="">Tour the Museum</a></div>
    <div id="subnavtab"><a href="">Program & Events</a></div>
    <div id="subnavtab"><a href="">Membership</a></div>
    <div id="subnavtab"><a href="">Donate</a></div>
</div>
<div id="featuredexhibit">
    Featured Exhibit - this can be a rotating menu of exhibits
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#subnav { margin-top: 20px; width: 740px; display: inline-block; }
#featuredexhibit { width: 732px; height: 200px; background-color: #A7A9AC; margin: 0; }
#subnavtab { background-color: #A1CD3A; float: left; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; margin: 0 5px 0 0; display: inline-block; }
```

I have tried using the Chrome Developer Tools to find the issue but I do not have any luck or I do not know what to look for.

Comment: Could be part of your problem (but I think browsers look past this for CSS). IDs should be unique for every element on the page. If you want to use same CSS attributes on a HTML element, use CSS Classes.

Comment: You must have some other CSS interfering. It looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/ZBgm8/

Comment: Post the CSS for subnavtab.

Comment: I tested it too in Chrome and Firefox on a MacBook Pro and it looks fine to me. No white spaces in between. There should be some other interference. If you have more CSS styles look for what's in for <div>

Comment: I have posted the CSS for `subnavtab` divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give a float to the subnav and then clear the featuredexhibit and then only it couldn't save a space between them.

```
#subnav{float: left;}
#featuredexhibit{clear: both;}
```

See this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/110/)**

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be any problem with your code.

Are you sure no other CSS is conflicting? Make sure the CSS tags you are using are from the last CSS added in the HTML.

For example,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css-1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css-2.css">
```

If there are common tags in "css-2.css", then it will over ride any similar tags of "css-1.css"

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not sure why the white space is there, but I got it fixed in Chrome by removing the `inline-block` and creating a clear both.

CSS

```
.subnav { margin-top: 20px; width: 740px; }
.featuredexhibit { width: 732px; height: 200px; background-color: #A7A9AC; margin: 0; }
.subnavtab { background-color: #A1CD3A; float: left; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; margin: 0 5px 0 0; }
.clear { clear: both; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="subnav">
    <div class="subnavtab"><a href="">Plan Your Visit</a></div>
    <div class="subnavtab"><a href="">Tour the Museum</a></div>
    <div class="subnavtab"><a href="">Program & Events</a></div>
    <div class="subnavtab"><a href="">Membership</a></div>
    <div class="subnavtab"><a href="">Donate</a></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="featuredexhibit">
    Featured Exhibit - this can be a rotating menu of exhibits
</div>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vFFx5/

Comment: Upon a quick Google search, it seems like it's a common issue: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but since I just ran into this issue I might as well point future visitors to this article: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

The problem seems to be that a new line counts as white space character in a row of inline-block elements. To solve this use floated blocks or flexbox.